# Does anyone have a "best practices" guide for nginx with http3/quic?

Tags: nginx, http3, quic

I've got quic working (verified by https://http3check.net/), but found that my site's upload speed was crippled as a result.

I've since added `http3_stream_buffer_size 1m;` (default is `64k`) and speeds have improved hugely, at least an order of magnitude.

Which is great, "problem solved".  But no-where told me to do this when setting quic up.  I wonder what other pitfalls I might be currently unaware of, or what other default settings should be changed for most people's use case.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the upload size and time required?

Comment: 100s/1000s of 5MB - 50MB files, "as quick as possible".  I've gone from 10Mbit to 200Mbit with the change shown

Comment: That still does not express the amount of time required. Crippled?

Comment: It was 10Mbit, which I consider very slow.  It's now 200Mbit, which I consider a lot better, certainly enough that I'm content with it - if it could be higher, great.  But `wget <isp test file>` seems to also top out at about 200Mbps when coming from a geographically different datacentre, so like I say, I'm content.

Comment: I'm of the intentionally ironic opinion that (many)  *"best practices are just another opinion"*.  Many settings and tuning options won't have "universally the same ; best for  all purposes" values , those will be use-case specific and need to be determined by the usual cycle of starting with defaults, monitoring and testing, identifying bottlenecks, making adjustments , followed by  more monitoring, a decision if the changed value is kept, reverted, further adjusted and then rinse and repeat for more monitoring and/or adjusting of other settings and new bottlenecks.

Comment: Since https://nginx.org/en/docs/quic.html still marks  QUIC and HTTP/3 support as experimental there probably is no large body of collective internet experience yet. Your Q&A might contribute more  if it didn't ask about off-topic learning materials elsewhere , but rather asked  a more on-topic question that can be answered here.  For example *"How to improve  nginx performance with HTTP3/QUIC?"* detailing  what you already found and learned  but also asking for more rule-of-thumb approaches and considerations [would be a great question](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681)...